# How to use SSH on Windows 10 Home Edition

Tags: windows-10, ssh

I tried setting up SSH using OpenSSH and Powershell on a netbook with Windows 10 Home Edition installed. An error resulted in Powershell which merely stated that SSH service couldn't be started on the computer. There is a message in the control panel which says that remote connection to the computer is not supported in the current edition of Windows. I'm guessing this is the reason I cannot setup an SSH service. If so, is there a way to support SSH on Windows 10 home edition?

Edit:
The error I'm receiving in Powershell after trying, `Start-Service sshd`, is as follows:

```
Service 'sshd (sshd)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service sshd on Computer
```

I went through the tutorial [Using the OpenSSH Beta in Windows 10 Fall Creators Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/12/15/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/) and the error results from trying the `Start-Service` script near the bottom.

Comment: Windows 10 Home, version 16299

Comment: From this post, https://blogs.vmware.com/feed-items/windows-10-fall-creators-update-comes-with-ssh-build-in-is-putty-dead/, I know I can use the OpenSSH Client, but what about OpenSSH server?

Comment: I answered 16299 which is actually the build. The version I'm running is 1709. So, the answer to your question is Windows 10 Home Version 1709.

Comment: I posted an edit to the original question.

Comment: Please see the latest edit to the original question.

Comment: I assume you have tried to uninstall and reinstall the feature.  If that still does not work I would report the issue to Microsoft.  The feature itself is a beta feature, so if you need SSH access to your machines, best to use a third-party solution at this time.

Comment: @poo_code Don't follow any other guide for installing and configuration than the wiki that exists on Microsoft's Powershell's [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) GitHub.  A significant amount of issues users experience when installing or setting up Win32-OpenSSH are from every Tom, Dick, and Harry creating a writeup that quickly becomes outdated instead of doing the sensible, rational, logical thing and simply linking to Win32-OpenSSH's [wiki](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

I got an SSH server running on Windows 10 Home. I wasn't able to install from "Optional Features" because "OpenSSH Server" wasn't showing up, probably because I am on Windows 10 Home instead of Windows Server.

I got the SSH server installed by following the [PowerShell installation in Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse#install-openssh-using-powershell).

```
# Install the OpenSSH Server
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0


Start-Service sshd
# OPTIONAL but recommended:
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
# Confirm the firewall rule is configured. It should be created automatically by setup.
Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *ssh*
```

Only do the following if the firewall rule above wasn't automatically created:

```
# There should be a firewall rule named "OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP", which should be enabled
# If the firewall does not exist, create one
New-NetFirewallRule -Name sshd -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue, [this solved it for me](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/770)

> Work around:
>
> Open control panel and navigate to Administrative Tools > Local
>   Security Policy > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment. Double
>   click Replace a Process Level Token Add NT Service\SSHD

Comment: Can you please quote something from the link here? Links-only answers are not encouraged here since the link could just die, etc

Comment: This doesn't apply to Windows 10 or any current build of Win32-OpenSSH at the time this answer was created _(or as of the date this comment was posted)_

Comment: Pretty sure Home editions don't include `secpol.msc` (the "Local Security Policy" snap-in for Computer Management). You might be able to pull it from another Windows machine, but if not, you'll either need a third-party program or to edit the registry directly, and NT privilege assignments are in a part of the registry not meant for mortal editors (the SAM).

Comment: @CBHacking _It's not likely that would work, as doing the same for `gpedit.msc` won't render a working Group Policy snap-in._ Regardless, **this answer doesn't even apply to Windows 10** _(it applies to Windows 7)_ **and didn't even apply to the most up-to-date version of Win32-OpenSSH _at the time the answer was posted_** _([v7.7.1.0p1-Beta](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/tags) - users were still failing to read the Install Instructions that existed on Win32-OpenSSH's wiki at that time, as doing so would have avoided the issue altogether)_.